# Force required to move the truck?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Can anyone help me with this concept as :
Let us suppose a truck is getting filled with coal from the hopper at constant rate of x kg/s and the truck driver is moving at constant speed of y m/s to fill the truck uniformly, what the force required to move the truck?
According to me if the speed is constant so there is no acceleration and force is nil but the concept is not true.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

According to Newton, *force required is directly proportional to the rate of change of momentum*.

Here you have a constant velocity which might lead you to believe that you have a constant momentum. But you don't have a constant momentum, the mass of the system is changing! So the rate of change of momentum would be the rate of change of mass into the constant velocity you have been given.

*PS*: Differentiating the term for momentum you get two terms, one of which is the one I've mentioned; the other is the mass into the rate of change of velocity (as a consequence of the chain rule of differentiation) which is zero in this case as the velocity is constant.

I hope that clears your doubt.